# how to get an index of the clicked rect element in svg group element in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I want to get an index of the clicked rect element.I am having multiple rectangles in one group element.I want to get the index of the particular clicked rect.

I have used like this.

```
var par=document.getElementById(this.parentgEle.id);                        
var childs = par.getElementsByTagName('rect');
        for (var i = 0, len = childs.length; i < len; i++) {
         this.currentRectIndex = i;
          console.log(this.currentRectIndex);
        }
```

using like this,i can get the index value correctly when i am removing the first rect.but if i am having three rects,removing last rect and then click the second rect it returns index value 1.
But if i am clicking the first rect means,value should be returned as 0.but it returns 1.because of using for loop.
How to avoid this.
can we get the index of the element without using loops.
anyone suggest me.
It should be great help for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have no selection criteria... so the loop just runs to it's limit, which is the number of child rects. You need to get the id of the clicked element and compare it to the id of an element in a given iteration, then remove if matching and break;.

Comment: thanks for your reply.actually i m having rect and at the corner of the rect having circle element.i m clicking the circle element after that i m perform dragging operation.but i want to know the rect index only.based on your suggestion,clicked element is circle and that is not matched in loop elements.because i m considering the rect elements only.this is the problem.how to solve this.

Comment: The basis of what you are doing is finding an element in a set. So you 1) need a way to id an element in a set, and 2) a method of moving through the set and comparing each of it's elements id's to the id you're trying to find. Should be very straight forward.

Comment: initially i dont know which element i have clicked.want to know the rectangle index.but based on your idea,clicked element is circle and that is not matched with the child elements in loop.got my question?

Comment: Showing just the loop code is not helpful.  Obviously there is other code doing things that you haven't explained well.  You should post a snippet or fiddle that shows a "working" example of what is going wrong.